# calculated column. How to get part of the text from another field?

Tags: calculated-column

I have a people column. I need to add a calculated column that can give me the domain. This formula `=RIGHT([ReportTo],LEN([ReportTo])-FIND("\",[ReportTo]))` gives me the name. But I need to get the domain so for contoso\dsmith will show contoso in the calculated column.

I was going to try this formula `=LEFT([ReportTo],INT(FIND("\",[ReportTo])-1))` but it looks like I can't use Person or Group type column in the calculated field. Any other suggestion on how to extract the domain name from person column?

Comment: If you can't use a Person/Group column in a calculated field, then how can the first formula work?

Comment: What version of SharePoint?

Comment: @Submits does it make any difference?

Comment: @MdMazzotti I ask because I would consider using CSR in 2013.

Comment: I see, but sticking to the original question, the answer is still no, you can't use a person field in a calculated field. Any other workaround is, well, just a workaround (to name a few: event receivers, workflows, CSR...)

Comment: actually it's [Me] not [ReportTo]. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

As you cant use the People or Group Column in the formula, i think the workaround is:

- create another text column
- create a workflow which will copy the items from people or group column into text column.
- Now use the Text column in your formula.

You can exclude that column from your view to avoid the misunderstanding.